# SQL Query to find records that fall between a start and end date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like the one below and I want to get the manager who is associated to a class BETWEEN a start_date AND end_date

| class_id | manager_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 999 | 2021-05-05 17:38:48 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 |
| 2 | 999 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 |
| 3 | 999 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 |
| 4 | 999 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 | NULL |

```
CREATE TABLE manager_class
(
   class_id int
   ,manager_id int
   ,start_time timestamp(3)
   ,end_time   timestamp(3)

)

INSERT INTO manager_class VALUES 

(1,999,'2021-05-05 17:38:48'::timestamp(3), '2021-05-05 17:39:38'::timestamp(3))

,(2,999,'2021-05-05 17:39:38'::timestamp(3), '2021-05-05 17:42:43'::timestamp(3))

,(3,999,'2021-05-05 17:42:43'::timestamp(3), '2021-05-05 17:47:45'::timestamp(3))

,(4,999,'2021-05-05 17:47:45'::timestamp(3), NULL)
```

Use Cases IF _param_start_date = 2021-05-05 17:30:48  _param_end_date = 2021-05-05 17:42:43
THEN RESULT should be

| class_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-05 17:38:48 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 |
| 2 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 |

IF _param_start_date = 2021-05-05 17:39:38  _param_end_date = 2021-05-05 17:42:43

| class_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 |

IF _param_start_date = 2021-05-05 17:39:38  _param_end_date = 2021-05-05 17:55:43

| class_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 |
| 3 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 |
| 4 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 | NULL |

IF _param_start_date = '2021-05-05 17:47:45' _param_end_date  = '2021-05-05 17:47:46'

| class_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 | NULL |

IF _param_start_date = '2021-05-05 17:39:38' _param_end_date = '2021-05-05 17:47:45'

| class_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 |
| 3 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 |
| 4 | 2021-05-05 17:47:45 | NULL |

IF _param_start_date = '2021-05-05 17:39:38' _param_end_date = '2021-05-05 17:40:00'

| class_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-05-05 17:39:38 | 2021-05-05 17:42:43 |

What I have done so far:

```
      SELECT    class_id
            ,mc.start_time
            ,mc.end_time 
    FROM    manager_class AS mc
            
    WHERE   mc.manager_id = 999
            AND ( 
                    (
                        mc.start_time BETWEEN param_start_time AND param_end_time /* replace param_start_time and param_end_time */
                        AND (param_end_time >=   mc.end_time)
                    )
                  
                    OR (
                         param_start_time >= mc.start_time
                         AND (param_end_time <=  mc.end_time OR mc.end_time IS NULL)
                        )   

                )
```

Comment: In your use cases you are giving 2 start dates. Do you mean a start and end

Comment: What if parameters are  start = 2021-05-05 17:39:00, end = 2021-05-05 17:40:00 ?

Comment: @bwakabats yes my bad its param_start_date and param_end_date

Comment: @serg for the use_case  start = 2021-05-05 17:39:00, end = 2021-05-05 17:40:00 ? the result will be the second record 2 2021-05-05 17:39:38 2021-05-05 17:42:43

Comment: Why the second row but not the first one? (7:39:00 .. 17:40:00) overlaps the first one too.

Comment: @Serg apologies again for 17:39:00 and 17:40:00, it will be both 1st and the second row                                                                                                                                  1 999 2021-05-05 17:38:48 2021-05-05 17:39:38
2 999 2021-05-05 17:39:38 2021-05-05 17:42:43

Comment: Ok, and  how `end_date` is NULL  should be  interpeted? Is any future  param , for example (18:00:00 .. 18:10:00) considered as matching a row (17:47:45 .. NULL) ?

Comment: @Serg  when end_date is NULL it means this is the current active association of the manager with the class So from 2021-05-05 17:47:45 is associated with class 4. so any date in future will statisfy  for eg the use cases below will be true for the last record                  IF _param_start_date = 2021-05-05 17:39:38 _param_end_date = 2021-05-05 17:55:43   IF _param_start_date = '2021-05-05 17:47:45' _param_end_date = '2021-05-05 17:47:46'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlapping intervals can be found this way. Not sure about NULL, this query considers
`mc.end_time is NULL` as an endless interval.

```
SELECT   class_id
        ,mc.start_time
        ,mc.end_time 
FROM    manager_class AS mc            
WHERE   mc.manager_id = 999
        AND mc.start_time <= param_end_time  
        AND (mc.end_time is NULL OR param_start_date <= mc.end_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters or table columns are allowed to contain null then your best bet seems to convert each to the appropriate [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and use the [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html) operator. Assuming all are defined as `timestamps without time zone` then:

```
select class_id
     , mc.start_time
     , mc.end_time 
  from manager_class  mc            
 where mc.manager_id = 999
   and tsrange(parm_start_time, parm_end_time,'[)') &&
       tsrange(mc,start_time,mc.end_time,'[)');
```